# Find a specific string or a regex in a text file in all lines using batch script and write them into another text file using for loop

Tags: regex, batch-file

I have a text file that contains these 9 lines:

```
Successfully started load asymmetric-song-851:bqjob_r08ac53fc_0000014bfdd9d371_1
Successfully started load asymmetric-song-851:bqjob_r44afbc8a_0000014bfdd9e792_1
Successfully started load asymmetric-song-851:bqjob_r7874a1e7_0000014bfdd9f7ca_1
Successfully started load asymmetric-song-851:bqjob_r11fb8a32_0000014bfdda0583_1
Successfully started load asymmetric-song-851:bqjob_r6b174b76_0000014bfdda1486_1
Successfully started load asymmetric-song-851:bqjob_r65772621_0000014bfdda239f_1
Successfully started load asymmetric-song-851:bqjob_r6e1918e0_0000014bfdda312d_1
Successfully started load asymmetric-song-851:bqjob_r08e15175_0000014bfdda3fa7_1
Successfully started load asymmetric-song-851:bqjob_r319141ff_0000014bfdda4e9e_1
```

I want to capture only jobid from each line,i.e. bqjob_r08ac53fc_0000014bfdd9d371_1. So the output text file should be like this:

```
bqjob_r0f2cb934_0000014bfe9c563c_1  
bqjob_r6022172e_0000014bfe9c6318_1  
bqjob_r67eae0a9_0000014bfe9c6f12_1  
bqjob_r56ab0212_0000014bfe9c7d67_1  
bqjob_r75d2e18d_0000014bfe9c89aa_1  
bqjob_r1c73e74f_0000014bfe9c9576_1  
bqjob_r31dae331_0000014bfe9ca28e_1  
bqjob_r56873b54_0000014bfe9caeb7_1  
bqjob_r0edb7092_0000014bfe9cbb8c_1
```

Comment: Looks like you have this string: 'Successfully started load asymmetric-song-851:' in all these 9 lines, and you just want to remove exactly this string.

Answer (score 1):

Split the string on `:` and echo the second part into a new file.

```
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%A in (data.txt) do echo %%B>>output.txt
```

This code assumes that your text file is called data.txt and that the lines you've shown us are the *only* lines in the file.

Comment: Actually,the input file that I have given here has all the successful executions,so there is a pattern and we can tokenise with ":''.But in the case of failure this input file would look like something else and no pattern would be there.So,I need to grab only jobids from that file.For that what should I do?I have already done what you have answered here.

Comment: Better to use `for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%B in ...` so that lines not containing `:` are ignored.

Comment: I would need sample data.

Comment: Successfully started load asymmetric-song-851:bqjob_r069b9290_0000014bfebbdfa9_1
Successfully started load asymmetric-song-851:bqjob_r76eb714e_0000014bfebbf0de_1
BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing job
'asymmetric-song-851:bqjob_r7853a02a_0000014bfebc0247_1': Not found: URI
gs://brillio_buck/Week/game_activity_android_2015-01-23_to_2015-01-25.tsv
Successfully started load asymmetric-song-851:bqjob_r7d6c8bc3_0000014bfebc0d8f_1
Successfully started load asymmetric-song-851:bqjob_r110f9c79_0000014bfebc19fc_1

Comment: You should add this to the question so that it can be formatted correctly.

Comment: See the formatted question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28947240/batch-script-to-find-a-regex-in-a-text-file-and-write-it-line-by-line-in-another/28947306?noredirect=1#comment46150776_28947306