# Batch script to find a regex in a text file and write it line by line in another text file

Tags: regex, batch-file

My text file accommodates these lines:

```
Successfully started load asymmetric-song-851:bqjob_r069b9290_0000014bfebbdfa9_1
Successfully started load asymmetric-song-851:bqjob_r76eb714e_0000014bfebbf0de_1                                  BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing job 'asymmetric-song-851:bqjob_r7853a02a_0000014bfebc0247_1':
Not found: URI gs://brillio_buck/Week/game_activity_android_2015-01-23_to_2015-01-25.tsv 
Some random text ...,,,, Some other random text
Successfully started load asymmetric-song-851:bqjob_r7d6c8bc3_0000014bfebc0d8f_1 
Successfully started load asymmetric-song-851:bqjob_r110f9c79_0000014bfebc19fc_1
Successfully started load asymmetric-song-851:bqjob_r56873b54_0000014bfe9caeb7_1  
Successfully started load asymmetric-song-851:bqjob_r0edb7092_0000014bfe9cbb8c_1
```

I want only jobids such as bqjob_r0edb7092_0000014bfe9cbb8c_1 in some other text file.So my output file should be as:

```
bqjob_r069b9290_0000014bfebbdfa9_1
bqjob_r76eb714e_0000014bfebbf0de_1
bqjob_r7853a02a_0000014bfebc0247_1
bqjob_r7d6c8bc3_0000014bfebc0d8f_1
bqjob_r110f9c79_0000014bfebc19fc_1
bqjob_r56873b54_0000014bfe9caeb7_1
bqjob_r0edb7092_0000014bfe9cbb8c_1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep -o`:

```
grep -o 'bqjob_r[^[:blank:]]*_[0-9]' file
bqjob_r069b9290_0000014bfebbdfa9_1
bqjob_r76eb714e_0000014bfebbf0de_1
bqjob_r7853a02a_0000014bfebc0247_1
bqjob_r7d6c8bc3_0000014bfebc0d8f_1
bqjob_r110f9c79_0000014bfebc19fc_1
bqjob_r56873b54_0000014bfe9caeb7_1
bqjob_r0edb7092_0000014bfe9cbb8c_1
```

Comment: I need a .bat (Batch File) to do this.No grep/sed/awk.

Comment: [`grep` is available on Windows also](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm)

Comment: It is not supported internally.I have to download some external tool.But my requirement is to do in batch file only.

Comment: Did you forget to write this clearly in your question? In any case you can take this regex and apply in any tool of your choice.

Comment: See the title once again.

Comment: Batch doesn't mean Windows

Comment: Ok.I want a .bat file to do this.

Comment: @anubhava - Rightly or wrongly, the [batch-file] tag (and its many synonyms) is explicitly defined to mean Windows, OS2, or DOS batch scripting. I've never been comfortable with that, but that is how the tag has evolved.